# Google recaptcha v2 all of a sudden will not respond with success

Tags: callback, captcha

I have Google Recaptcha v2 on 4 different sites. They have been working fine for years (a very long time at least). Dont know when it started as I was just recently informed about it, but all of the Recaptcha's are no longer working.
The response is always the same: "Cannot verify that you are human". In other words, I am no longer getting a successful response.
Nothing has changed in the sites or the code. Could it be that I updated to latest php version? Or did Google change something? Have no idea why they are not working or how to fix.

```
     if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
     $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
     }
     if(!$captcha){
       include ('./forms/sectionhead.tpl');  
       echo '<h4 style="color:#c30000;text-align:center;">You must check the reCaptcha form to send this email.</h4>';
       include ('./forms/contactform.php'); 
       include ('./forms/contactend.php');
       exit;
                 }
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
     $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
     if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
       echo '<h4 style="color:#c30000;text-align:center;">Sorry, we cannot verify that you are human</h4><br><br>';
     } else {

     //send email
```

Any thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated as I am lost ATM
Thanx

Comment: I am beginning to think it is related to a php 7.3 upgrade? Can anyone verify this or not?

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS RIDICULOUS !!!

I had found the issue with allow_url_fopen in another post. And checked that it was on and it was.

/$ grep allow_url_fopen /usr/local/lib/php.ini
allow_url_fopen = On

Rather than ssh, decided to turn on php error reporting through cpanel WHM and in the Multiphp ini editor it said allow_url_fopen DISABLED !!!

WTF !!

Enabled and all working - dont want to even think of the hours wasted on this.

Why ssh says ON and cpanel says OFF ???